# Prime ideal in the ring of integers of the number field $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ with $x^{3}=2$

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

In an exercise of the book *Algebraic Theory of Numbers* by Samuel, one must show that--in the integer ring $\mathcal{O_k}$ of the number field extension $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ where $x^{3}=2$--the ideal $x\mathcal{O_k}$ is a prime ideal. As a hint the author says to consider what consider the decomposition of ideal $2\mathcal{O_k}$ is in $\mathcal{O_k}$.

But I do not know how to use the hint to show this assertion. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Since $x^3=2$, and $8=N(2)=N(x^3)=N(x)^3$, we have $N(x)=2$. But then $|\mathcal{O}_K/(x)|=2$, where $|\cdot |$ is cardinality as a set, hence the quotient is a ring of size $2$, and so must be a field. Since the quotient is an integral domain, the ideal generated by $x$ is prime.

Comment: Of the fact that $N(x)=2$ as concluded what $|\mathcal{O}_K/(x)|=2$?

Comment: @user67427 I don't understand your question, can you restate it more clearly?

Comment: Do not understand why the quotient is a ring of size 2.

Comment: @user67427 the norm of an ideal is its index, and the norm of a principal ideal is equal to the norm of a generator. So I use the easy computation that $N(x)=2$ and transfer to the definition of the norm as the index (i.e. the cardinality of the quotient) to determine the quotient size.

Comment: @user67427 this also supposes you've seen an ideal norm before, if not you should say so and add more context to your question so us readers can better understand what's expected of you. Since you've gotten to decomposition of ideals, it seemed a safe bet you'd seen the ideal norm before.